# When writing a typical reducer which serves the purpose of loading data from API, should we specify all state fields in every action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Throughout many React/Redux projects I worked on, I noticed there's a repeating pattern of specifying values for all fields in the reducer's state in both initialState and every action case:

```
const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    error: null,
    data: null
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'DATA_LOADING':
            return {
                ...state,
                error: null,
                loading: true,
                data: null
            };
        case 'DATA_COMPLETE':
            return {
                ...state,
                error: null,
                data: action.payload.data
            };
        case 'DATA_FAILURE':
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload.error
                data: null,
                loading: false
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Now, let's say that we did our homework and isolated this reducer from other reducers and combined it with them by using combineReducers.

1. In this case, this reducer's state belongs only to this reducer, and the above "...state" is basically useless because all other fields are also specified.
2. The three fields in this typical kind of reducer are exclusive: we can't have "data" while we're loading, nor can we have error if we get data, etc. So in each case there is one relevant line, all others are just specifying that the rest is void
3. Also note that in case of 'DATA_COMPLETE' above, I "accidentally" omitted to specify "loading = false", which is a bug, very easily missed because of all the repetition.
4. If we want to change one of the fields' name, we have to change it in 4 different places - initialState and each action.type.
5. For all of them, when we want to 'empty' them, we have to wonder - "did I set error in initialState to 'null', or 'undefined', or... ?", and "did I set data to 'null', or [], or 'undefined', or...?"

So we resolve all these problems with a very simple, less code, easy to read alternative:

```
const initialState = {};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'DATA_LOADING':
            return {
                loading: true
            };
        case 'DATA_COMPLETE':
            return {
                data: action.payload.data
            };
        case 'DATA_FAILURE':
            return {
                error: action.payload.error
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

So basically, no field means !field. No field 'error' in state, that means there's no error! No 'data' in state, that means data is empty! In all my use-cases, this kind of reducer contained zero bugs, was just-as-useful as the version above, and has less code and reads easier.

But now, this turned out to be atypical and in our company we had a discussion about this, with the following reasons being said against this approach, and apparently more important for some people than the reasons above:

1. If we set specify one field's value, it is not obvious what we are setting other fields to
2. We don't have all the fields listed in one place so it's hard to read
3. Other reducers are written in the traditional way, we don't want to have different styles of reducers around

I am very interested to hear the StackOverflow community's opinion on this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting both `data` and `error` to `null` when you call LOADING, does it make sense to then specify them again when you call either COMPLETE or FAILURE?

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'DATA_LOADING':
            return {
                ...state,
                error: null,
                loading: true,
                data: null
            };
        case 'DATA_COMPLETE':
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.payload.data,
                loading: false
            };
        case 'DATA_FAILURE':
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload.error
                loading: false
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
```

}

My preference is that you should not be removing properties from the state if they should always be there. In the case of something like an Array of resources, it makes sense to be able to remove and delete them, but in the case of non-dynamic properties, I think it is best to always have them in the state. That way you always know exactly what properties exist at a given time, and you can look at `initialState` and know exactly what the state is going to look like.

Additionally, if you find yourself writing this same logic in many different reducers, it may be beneficial to have one generic reducer that you can combine with your specific state reducers, so that you only have to write this logic once.

A good way of doing that is to combine this generic data fetching reducer with another reducer where you want to use this code, specifying a namespace or some other unique value that can be appended to the action, so you don't have to worry about having different actions for different reducers.

In other words, a higher order function that takes a namespace and this generic reducer, and returns a namespaced generic reducer, which you can then combine with other reducers, exposing this logic throughout your application on a namespaced level.

Answer (score 0):

For any interested parties, I answered my own question by writing a blog at Medium.com, https://medium.com/@darko.maksimovic/optimize-your-fetch-data-reducer-78e0812f0e4e

In essence, option 1 from original question is much better than the "traditional" approach.